# Status line in C Terminal program

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, status, minicom

I am running a terminal program written in c/c++ over shell.
It is same like minicom for UART.

I am looking for the way how I can create “Status Line on the bottom” same like attached picture (bottom line of minicom: CTRL-A Z line which is always there as a GUI).
For sure it is not just printf/cout but needed some extended API, I guess.
Has anybody done that? Or may be some idea how to proceed?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are various libraries that allow you to do things like this. A well known one is ncurses.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

You can do it yourself using terminal control system calls, but that tends to be rather tedious and platform-specific.

Comment: I looked some tutorials on tlpg.org but I couldn’t find the way to print status line as mentioned above on the bottom line of Terminal permanently and after that do in/out from the top left corner.

Comment: Libraries like Ncurses allow you to print anywhere within a text 'window' you define. It's up to you to write code to actually print the status bar and manage the position of you cursor.